# Why are the disciples addressed differently in different contexts?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospels

At John 21: 4-5 we see a post-resurrection event when Jesus addresses the disciples as children:

> Just as day was breaking, Jesus stood on the beach; yet the disciples
>   did not know that it was Jesus.  Jesus said to them, “Children, have
>   you any fish?

Elsewhere, we see Jesus referring to them as brothers:

> Then Jesus said to them, “Do not be afraid. Go and tell my brothers to
>   go to Galilee; there they will see me."(Matt 28:10)

I am curious to know the significance of two different types of attributes viz. 'brothers' and 'children' used by Jesus while referring to his disciples.

What do the teachings of Catholic Church say about their significance?